# firebase addvalueeventlistener not being triggered in one device

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm having a problem with one specific device (my main device which is galaxy s7)

as described here :
[Firebase addValueEventListener not being triggered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38470948/firebase-addvalueeventlistener-not-being-triggered)

the addvalueeventlistener won't trigger and as suggested i checked if i have connection using this :

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state

and i'm actually not connected

the problem is that one the developing device it's working great and on other it's not.

what am i missing here ?

this is the code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
localCountryDB = ((GlobalState) this.getApplication()).getCountry();
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
myRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child(localCountryDB);
FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
if (mAuth.getCurrentUser()!=null)
userID = user.getUid();

DatabaseReference connectedRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(".info/connected");
connectedRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
boolean connected = snapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);
if (connected) {
System.out.println("connected");
} else {
System.out.println("not connected");
}
}

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
System.err.println("Listener was cancelled");
}
});

valueEventListener = myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
getUserData(dataSnapshot);
}



@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

String Hello;
Hello="a";
}
});
```

Comment: Could you show a complete and minimal sample of code that exhibits the problem you're seeing?

Comment: Why the unvote @DougStevenson? the code is attached

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem

The problem is that :

```
mAuth.getCurrentUser()
```

actually returned a user, an old user which was already deleted from the authentication data so i had to

```
mAuth.signout()
```

once i did it the connection was "connected" again and the ValueEventListener triggers

The problem is that i don't know how to catch this bug since trigger doesn't fire.

Comment: I am having an issue with ValueEventListener not triggered and I believe it could be related to this! have you found the way to detect the "wrong" users to force the logout?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

- Add the internet permission to the manifest
- Set the firebase database security rules read to true

Comment: Do you actually have internet connection? Show your code

Comment: i do, wifi & data + on the FirebaseDatabase.getInstance() line while i'm debugging i can see the Firebase database URL

Comment: @SamsadCV check the database security rules